# How to make a rest service call using dojo?

Tags: rest, dojo

Can anyone tell me how to call a rest service using dojo.io.script.

```
try {
  dojo.io.script.get({
    url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json",
    content: {
      q: "#dojo"
    },
    callbackParamName: "callback"
  }).then(function(data) {

  });
} catch (e) {
  alert(e);
}
```

I tried using the above code, but I didn't get a response. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can call HTTP GET like below:

```
// The "xhrGet" method executing an HTTP GET
dojo.xhrGet({
    // The URL to request
    url: "get-message.php",
    // The method that handles the request's successful result
    // Handle the response any way you'd like!
    load: function(result) {
        alert("The message is: " + result);
    }
});
```

For more information check [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/ajax/) here.

Another example is [here](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/post-request-using-new-dojo-request-xhr-td3987429.html).